# IE 9 Javascript Window Variable is null.. Works on IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

at some point in my code, I access a javascript variable this way:

```
var DASHBOARD = document.parentWindow.parent.Dashboard;
```

Where parent's value is {object Window} and its type is DispHTMLWindow2.
It works OK on IE8 or in IE9 compatibility view but when I cannot make it work on IE9.

On IE9, the value of document.parentWindow.parent.Dashboard is undefined and its type Undefined. I also noticed that parent's value is {...} and its type is [Object, Window] on IE 9.

Is there a different way of accessing the variable Dashboard in IE 9?

Example:

layouts.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Create new Layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .border-top { height: 5px; background-color: #B2B2B2;}
        .border-left { width: 3px; height: 100%; background-color: #B2B2B2;}
        .content { height: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./container/includes/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./container/includes/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dada = "123";
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <iframe name="remote_iframe_0" src="layouts2.aspx" id="remote_iframe_0" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

layouts2.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .border-top { height: 5px; background-color: #B2B2B2;}
        .border-left { width: 3px; height: 100%; background-color: #B2B2B2;}
        .content { height: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./container/includes/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./container/includes/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        AAAA
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I access variable dada at the debugger; in layouts2.aspx? Considering both pages are on the same domain.

Comment: Just to be sure : are the two windows served by the same domain/port ?

Comment: The parent and child frame are on the same domain and port.

Comment: `parentWindow` is a Microsoft only parameter. I guess they removed it in IE9 to be compatible. Use `parent`, or `opener` instead.

Comment: I tried almost every possible path in the Dom to find my variable but I can't find it in IE9. The scenario is like that:
A main window with a variable Dashboard declared inside
; B iframe of A (both same domain), and I'm trying to access the variable from B.

Comment: Have you tried: window.parent.dada ? (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)

Comment: Yep that worked ! Thank you dystroy and Edward !

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
window.parent.dada
```

Reference:

http://w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

http://w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: edited to make your links clickable. But really, w3schools is not considered a good resource.